# create custom refactor/generate functionality in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am looking to extend my development speed by implementing several macros and learning new ones. I was wondering if it was possible to create custom refactor functionality in Android Studio.

The reason I want this is for example to rightclick on a layout id in code and refactor or generate all views from that layout and set all declares and findviewbyids (or do the same functionality but with Butter Knife) in the class and in the oncreate functions. Doing a lot of repetitive is not that great and development time will go up for me (especially when doing multiple input screens like this).

Is this possible? any alternatives known?

Comment: Since Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA, you may wish to research how to extend IDEA, then see if the same approach works for Android Studio.

Comment: Yes that seems to be the way to go about it, thanks. Will be quite some work though but it will benefit me.